# NodeJS Joi validation - send only modified values

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, joi

I have been working on a way, on how to properly sanitize payloads coming from react front end, to node js express backend mongo database. What I am trying to achieve, is that the backend will only send modified data. For example, a request comes with {a, b, c} but only {a, c} was modified, so only a and c will be sent to the database. From what I have been reading the [JOI documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.1) I wasnt able to find their built in method.

For context, here is the code for updating a user:

```
const updateUser = async (req: MyR, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    await userEditSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error });
    return;
  }
  try {
    const user: IUser | null = await updateUserById(id, req.body);
    if (user) {
      res.json({ message: `user ${id} updated`, user });
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: `user ${id} not found` });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
};
```

And here is code for JOI validation schema

```
const userEditSchema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum(),
    firstName: Joi.string(),
    lastName: Joi.string(),
    email: Joi.string().email({ tlds: { allow: false } }),
    id: Joi.string()
})
```

How can I sanitize the payload, be only sending values/user inputs that were modified?

Comment: Do you ask how from the react app send only values that have changed ?

Comment: I dont think, that we do. Could you provide an example, of how that happens?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. So JOI may tell you whether a certain object is valid based on a rule. But JOI cannot tell you what differences you have compared to the current DB state. In order to get changes, you need to load the record from the DB and compare it to the request. And that does not solve the issue entirely because when you come to the update, I DB may have changed.

Comment: Why would the DB be changed? If we were comparing the single entry of the targeted user entry for edit, wouldnt it work like 1. We create a PATCH/PUT request from the Front End 2. Back end pulls the entry to compare, what values are different 3. After comparison, only the different values are sent.

Comment: Is ONLY one user supposed to use your app? Another request may have changed the record between reading it and writing it from the database

Comment: In theory, only 1-2 users would be able to manage those accounts. As an example, an admin would only be able to update user information, such as name, last name, username, email and etc.

Comment: JOI is not comparing tool, you should either implement it yourself or use another library. `function getUpdatedProps(fromRest, fromDB)  {  /// your logic goes here }`